# How to change Google chart font size?

Tags: charts, svg, google-visualization

Is it possible to change Google chart font size, my problem is that when i shrink width and height of whole chart, text becomes small and unreadable, any way to custom set font size?

[image]

Also is it posible to change tooltip size , described as a in the image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

legend.textStyle and tooltip.textStyle control this as documented for scatter charts for instance [here](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart.html#Configuration_Options)

Answer (score 21):

in options, set legend and tooltip by

*{legend:{textStyle:{fontSize:'xx', fontName:'xx'}}}

{tooltip:{textStyle:{fontSize:'xx', fontName:'xx'}}}*

Check out [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart#Configuration_Options) for more details

Answer (score 6):

For Areachart:

```
var options = {
tooltip: {textStyle:  {fontName: 'TimesNewRoman',fontSize: 12,bold: false}}
}
```

Thanks,
Arun v